# React / Material-UI: Use variable reference in custom theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way in Material-UI (React) to use a reference in a custom theme to a variable defined in the same theme? For example, the component `MuiBottomNavigation` should use the primary color (main) as background.

```
import { createTheme, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#f6b1b2'
        }
    },
    components: {
        MuiBottomNavigation: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    // This is not working
                    backgroundColor: {palette.primary.main}
                },
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. there is no such API to access the theme when you define it. So something like this wouldn't work

```
styleOverrides: {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme => theme.palette.primary.main
  },
}
```

To workaround this you can put the commonly shared value into a variable and reference it:

```
const primaryMain = '#f6b1b2';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: primaryMain,
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiBottomNavigation: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: primaryMain,
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

If you only need to access a default theme variable, you can create one and reference it like this:

```
const defaultTheme = createTheme();

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiBottomNavigation: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: defaultTheme.palette.primary.main,
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by creating several themes and then merging them into one:

```
// Define all your default styles
const themeBase = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#f6b1b2"
    }
  }
});

// Define all your component styles
const themeComponents = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiBottomNavigation: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: themeBase.palette.primary.main
        },
      }
    }
  }
});

const theme = createTheme({
  ...themeBase,
  components: themeComponents.components,
});
```

Of course, you wouldn't need to create an extra theme for the components. You could also just insert them into the final `theme`.

An advantage of using this method, instead of defining your colors in a variable (e.g., `const primaryMain = "#f6b1b2"`), is that you can also access the composed colors, such as `themeBase.palette.primary.light`, which is [calculated](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#providing-the-colors-directly) from `themeBase.palette.primary.main`.